# multiple Kruskal-Wallis instead of ANOVA for non-normally distributed data

Tags: anova, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, kruskal-wallis-test

Apologies in advanced if I supply too little or vague information, since I am a complete newbie in stats and using this forum.

So I did a study which evaluated psychopathic personality traits, coping skills and impulsivity on three different groups of people (G1, G2, G3). Impulsivity was gauged with a Go/No-Go task from which I derived various statistics (false alarm rate, hit rate, percentage correct, d-prime, etc.). Since the data from the impulsivity task were non-normal (negative skew and non-linear) I used Kruskal-Wallis tests on each variable of the impulsivity measure to determine if the groups significantly varied on each of them.

1. Should I correct my alpha value with Bonferroni correction for the multiple Kruskal-Wallis tests I ran? Since all the variables are derived from the same data, that is, they reflect different aspects of the same construct?
2. The groups G1, G2 and G3 are significantly different in Gender and Ethnicity and on my other analysis (ANOVAs for the psychopathic traits and coping skills) I controlled for them by including them as covariates. What alternative to I have with the impulsivity variables? Should I run additional Kruskal-Wallis tests to see if the Gender and Ethnicity groups significantly differ in these variables?

I appreciate any help!